# Downloading GitHub QML style file for use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, download, qml, github

I am trying to download a QML-style from GitHub and add it to QGIS styles for use, this is how it looks like:

[image]

How can I do this? I'd really like to use this style.

Comment: what is the github link - there should be a download (or right save as option)

Comment: https://github.com/kevelyn1/qgis_styles/tree/master/papercut_style, this is the link, thank you for the help

Comment: use the raw button > https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevelyn1/qgis_styles/master/papercut_style/papercut_relief.qml (right click save as)

Answer (score 5):

[Click on it](https://github.com/kevelyn1/qgis_styles/blob/master/papercut_style/papercut_relief.qml), then right click "Raw" and choose "Save as..."

[image]

Here for example with firefox in german:

[image]

Comment: I have saved the file, thank you, however when trying to add a style file to qgis is not showing :( what are the steps of opening this file into qgis?

Comment: @Adriana right click your layer, choose "properties". On the bottom you will now find a button: "style". Click it and choose "load style".

Comment: Yes, I did that, however, the file is not showing on my folder in order to open it, I'm thinking it has to do something with what it says on the instructions: "To use the style, please copy together with paper_texture.png file to your folder and replace in .qml file the folderpath of the paper_texture.png file", since I did not do these steps and just saved as, and I do not know how to "copy together with long file and replace folder path. thank you for your help

Comment: yes you need the png's it's referenced in the style. (qml).

Comment: what you mean referenced? how do I add or download the png? when I save as the qml. file as raw is saved as a text file, that's why qgis is not reading it, but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly download this style

Comment: the png is referenced in the qml to "F:/styles/paper_texture.png" you will need to edit that location for your own pc local drive (c:/ or d:/) "paper_texture.png" so it can load correctly

Comment: How can I save the papercut_relief.qml code as a QML file? When I click on "raw" and try to save as, I am only able to save as a text document.